# How to get form input value?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, input

I'm beginner for PHP. I have a form on the website and this form getting title and description values specific websites (with preg_match).

I want to add url input this form and when you add url and press submit button its auto get fields. Example

Frontend:

```
<input name="url">https://testdomain.com/posts/6412</input>
```

Backend:

```
$link = 'input values here';
```

Result:

Form fields (title and description getting) refresh or with ajax.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Then you can use `$("#formid").serialize()` to get all the input values.

Comment: If you're not using a library like jQuery, there's nothing that automatically gets all form fields for AJAX.

Comment: Can you show an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Form and add the fields inside it..
In action, attribute add the file name where you want to post the form..

**Form.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="submit.php">
    <input name="url" value="https://testdomain.com/posts/6412">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**submit.php**

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $link = $_POST['url'];
    }
?>
```

With AJAX

**Form.php**

```
 <form method="POST" id="form" action="submit.php">
    <div id="result"></div>
    <input name="url" value="https://testdomain.com/posts/6412">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            $("#result").html(response);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

submit.php

```
<?php 
    $link = $_POST['url'];
    echo $link;
?>
```

for ajax, you must have to add jquery library before ajax code

Comment: Thank you very much Moiz its working fine! :)

Comment: Check i had updated for ajax also :)

Comment: Im tried and with this method page loaded two copy. Empty fields and loaded fields. But whatever first method working :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, you can use its `serialize()` method to get all the form inputs.

```
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            $("#result").html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Note, however, that `serialize()` won't include the submit button itself. That's only submitted automatically in normal form submissions. If the server expects something like `$_POST['submit']` to be set, you have to add it explicitly, e.g.

```
data: $(this).serialize() + '&submit=true',
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your form, make sure to include method="post" in the form attribute section.

```
                <form class="contact-form" method="post" action="processes/contactusform">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="sr-only">Name</label>
                        <input type="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" name="name" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message" class="sr-only">Message</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="7" placeholder="Message" name="message" required /></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-send-message btn-md" value="Send Message" name="submit">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

In your php code, you can refer to your inputs using:

```
    $name = $_POST['name']; //you use 'name' because the value attribute in html for that specific input is set to "name"
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
```

Your welcome